# OpenCV + Python Related: Is a conversion from RGBA to RGB necessary in this case?

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv
...
#Let boundaryPixel be the 24-bit representation of the color of the rectangle 
#(e.g., RED in this case)`
boundaryPixel = cv.RGB(255, 0, 0)`
print("valueIs: " + str(boundaryPixel))`
#(0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 0.0), 4 channels reversed?`
...
```

Given the snippet above, I would like to know why does OpenCV return the value in this way (i.e., reversed and with 4 channels instead of 3)?

What I am trying to do overall is that I am trying to scan an image, searching for pixels with the RGB values of (255, 0, 0). My initial attempt was to define what a boundary-pixel would be in this case, and then just have my loop search for those pixels and store them somewhere. Doing some research, I found out that the 4th value would be the Alpha channel, correct? So, I currently have something like (RED, GREEN, BLUE, ALPHA), but I am not sure if I would need to convert the 4 channels into the 3 channels to achieve what I want: which is compare the currentPixel at some location (X0, Y0) and if it has those same values (255, 0, 0), I want to keep them for further image processing.

Currently I am also using PIL's `getdata()` method to obtain the values of the pixels, hence why I wanted to define what a boundary-pixel is to begin with. Where will I run into some problems and is my approach well thought out? I don't want to convert the entire image. I just want to be able to compare that pixel with one that I have already defined.

Thanks and if you guys need more information or if something wasn't clear, please me know!

Comment: I came across this post here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088664/how-do-you-compare-pixels-in-python) and it seems like there WILL be an issue since I am using an ALPHA band. I don't really want to use that however. Any other alternative? Thanks.